# sudo whoami vs sudo echo `whoami`

Tags: shell, ubuntu, scripting, sudo

Simply put, why is this? Wouldn't it make more sense that sudo echo `whoami` returns root too?

Cheers

```
me:~$ whoami
me
me:~$ sudo whoami 
root
me:~$ sudo echo `whoami`
me
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is happening because `whoami` get substituted prior the sudo and echo. Basically:

```
sudo echo `whoami`
```

first becomes

```
sudo echo me
```

and then it sudo get executed.

Answer (score 3):

Reason is like @Andriy said, but if you want print **root**:
just change backquote place:

```
sudo `echo whoami`
```

it will print: **root**